# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..." in object literal

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I've found this code in some tutorial. How does it work? Why isn't it working for me (I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`)?

```
const commentReducer = (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state, //error on this line
    completed: !state.completed
  }
}
```

Comment: In the image showing the error, shouldn't var be const?

Comment: @miah It doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is using [object spread properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread), which are not a part of ECMAScript 6. They are currently an ECMAScript proposal at stage 3. To use them, you have to configure Babel to use `stage-3` preset.